# xts assignment changes column class

Tags: r, xts

I have a data.frame earlyCloses defined as follows:

```
earlyCloses <- read.table('EarlyCloses.txt', header=T, colClasses= c(rep("character", 3)))
earlyCloses

   StartDate    EndDate EarlyClose
1 2012-12-24 2012-12-24      13:00
```

I define a xts object pricesXts as follows:

```
prices <- read.table('sample.txt', header=T, colClasses=c("character", "numeric"))
pricesXts = xts(prices$Close, as.POSIXct(prices$Date, tz='America/New_York'))
colnames(pricesXts) = c("Close")
pricesXts$CloseTime = NA
pricesXts

              Close CloseTime
2012-12-21 13190.84        NA
2012-12-24 13139.08        NA
2012-12-26 13114.59        NA
2012-12-27 13096.31        NA
2012-12-28 12938.11        NA
```

Now I execute a for loop over the rows of earlyCloses and set the CloseTime of pricesXts.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(earlyCloses)) {
   pricesXts[paste(earlyCloses[i,"StartDate"], earlyCloses[i,"EndDate"], sep='/'), 2] = earlyCloses[i,"EarlyClose"]
}
pricesXts

           Close      CloseTime
2012-12-21 "13190.84" NA       
2012-12-24 "13139.08" "13:00"  
2012-12-26 "13114.59" NA       
2012-12-27 "13096.31" NA       
2012-12-28 "12938.11" NA
```

Why has the class of the Close column in the xts object changed from numeric to character?  Is this because an xts object is represented internally as a matrix?  Is there a way to avoid this conversion?

Comment: looking at function `xts`, it seems to be the case (`matrix`).

Answer (score 2):

`xts` is encoded internally as a matrix ( better performances). Since you want just to store the Early Close, you can convert it to a numeric , for example:

```
strptime(earlyCloses$EarlyClose,'%H:%M')$hour
```

Then

```
for (i in 1:nrow(earlyCloses))
   pricesXts[paste(earlyCloses[i,"StartDate"], 
                   earlyCloses[i,"EndDate"], 
                   sep='/'), 2] <- strptime(earlyCloses$EarlyClose,'%H:%M')$hour


           Close CloseTime
2012-12-21 13191        NA
2012-12-24 13139        13
2012-12-26 13115        NA
2012-12-27 13096        NA
2012-12-28 12938        NA
```